# Using `dired-do-compress-to` with `tramp`

Tags: dired, tramp

Within a `eamcs -q` session and in a `tramp` `dired` buffer and call `dired-do-compress-to` on a file, I got this eror

```
zip I/O error: No such file or directory
zip error: Could not create output file (/ssh:user@192.168.0.99:/home/user/Downloads/a.zip)
```

However, calling `dired-do-compress` on the same file is just OK.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce it with Emacs 28.0.50. Looks like an error; pls report it as Emacs bug via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.